# Documentclass[landscape]{foils} - \pause doesn't work

Tags: pause

Hey I have to use specific style from my job and `\pause` command doesn't work - "undefined control sequence". I'm using `Documentclass[landscape]{foils}` documentclass. What can I do?

Comment: `\pause` is a command from the `beamer` class. the `foils` class is entirely separate/

Comment: ok, but is there an easy way to obtain the same effect?

Comment: sorry I haven't looked at foils since last century, but using beamer commands wont work they have no code in common.

Comment: Where is the `foils` class? I have not come across it and it is not in my uptodate LaTeX distribution?

Comment: @PeterWilson it's on ctan, it's not in texlive for licence reasons, basically it was popular in the 1990's I'm not sure why Markov is using it now https://ctan.org/pkg/foiltex

Comment: The `foils` class output was meant to be printed on transparencies. Very outdated technology.

Comment: Clearly there's no need for `\pause` when you're working on real, physical overhead projector slides … Seriously: Consider using `beamer`.